# How to bind Control-Tab in Bash?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to bind <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to a shell function in Bash.

I've tried the following things in my .bashrc:

```
bind -m vi-insert -x '"\C-\t": some_user_function'
bind -m vi-insert -x '"\C-TAB": some_user_function'
bind -m vi-insert -x '"\C-\TAB": some_user_function'
```

But neither work. I couldn't find anything in `help bind` and `man bash` either.

However `bind -m vi-insert -x '"\C-x": some_user_function'` work so it is clearly a problem with telling `bind` to recognize the tab key somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short: terminals don't do that.

long: bash runs in a terminal.  While some provide an escape sequence for <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>, you're unlikely to find one doing this for <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> unless you specially configure it yourself (using features of a specific terminal emulator).

Comment: Oh, I knew about Shift-Tab and thought that Control-Tab will work because the **Readline Initialization** and **Readline Key Bindings** sections of `man bash` suggested that they understand `TAB` and `\t` - so I thought that I can combine that with the control key.

Comment: no - it's already a control-key, and only terminals that allow configuring X events (or Windows events...) will be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it. It makes perfect sense now.