# How can I remap crtl-z?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, stty

I have several keys remapped successfully, but ctrl-z is being stubborn..

I can get these to work:

```
stty susp undef
bind '"\C-f": undo'
bind '"\C-Z": undo'
```

..but not:

```
bind '"\C-z": undo'
```

It returns the `^@` symbol and resets the line. This symbol is the "null character" for emacs https://superuser.com/questions/927597/what-is-caret-at-under-emacs, so it looks like I have unset the default stty binding, but not been able to set it to something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind Control-Tab in Bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353608/how-to-bind-control-tab-in-bash).  Control-Z is the same code as control-z.

Comment: `stty` doesn't matter.  There are several possibilities for duplicates, which amount to pointing out that in a terminal, case doesn't matter when using the `control` modifier.

Comment: @ThomasDickey ah, that's it.. I thought capitalization did matter because I think you can use shift as a modifier.. but it turns out one of the terminal key shorts for Konsole was blocking.

Comment: this didnt need to be closed.. a question on if capitalization matters to `bind` specifically is different than how to use it in general